# Cypress - extract URL info

Tags: cypress

I have this URL :

https://www.acme.com/book/passengers?id=h1c7cafc-5457-4564-af9d-2599c6a37dde&hash=7EPbMqFFQu8T5R3AQr1GCw&gtmsearchtype=City+Break

and want to store these values :

id=h1c7cafc-5457-4564-af9d-2599c6a37dde
hash=7EPbMqFFQu8T5R3AQr1GCw

for use in a later test.

How do I extract these values from the URL? I am using Cypress. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does this help you: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url.html#Syntax?

Comment: Seems more like a JS issue than Cypress. I suggest you trying to extract the values using the match method provided by JS using regular expressions, store the original URL within a variable and start manipulating until getting the desired value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the following steps and that's all there is to it.

You can put this snippet into `before()` hooks of your spec file and you can access them wherever you want.

```js
cy.location().then(fullUrl => {
      let pathName = fullUrl.pathname
      let arr = pathName.split('?');
      let arrayValues = arr[1].split('&');
      cy.log(arrayValues[0]);
      cy.log(arrayValues[1]);
      cy.log(arrayValues[2]);
    })
```

Comment: This is wrong actually, you will discover `pathname` component of fullUrl does not have the search parameters. Read the Cypress example here [Make assertions about every location property](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Make-assertions-about-every-location-property) to see your error.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs the correct answer, use the `cy.location('search')` to extract the search part of the location data.

Then for convenience, convert it to a javascript object with key/value pairs for each item.

Finally, store it in a Cypress alias to use later in the test.

```js
cy.location('search')
  .then(search=> {
    const searchValues = search.split('?')[1].split('&')
    // yields: [
    //   id=h1c7cafc-5457-4564-af9d-2599c6a37dde, 
    //   hash=7EPbMqFFQu8T5R3AQr1GCw, 
    //   gtmsearchtype=City+Break
    // ]
    
    const searchMap = searchValues.reduce((acc,item) => {
      const [key,value] = item.split('=')
      acc[key] = value.replace('+', ' ')
      return acc
    }, {})
    // yields: {
    //   id: "h1c7cafc-5457-4564-af9d-2599c6a37dde", 
    //   hash: "7EPbMqFFQu8T5R3AQr1GCw", 
    //   gtmsearchtype: "City Break"
    // }

    cy.wrap(searchMap).as('searchMap')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Srinu Kodi's answer I got it working changing `...then(fullUrl => ...` to
`...then((fullUrl) => ...`

Comment: No, the brackets will not change how the code works, they are purely cosmetic.